# Is this map from $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ to $P(X)$ one-to-one?

Tags: measure-theory

For a discrete set $X$ with $n$ elements, there can be finite many $\Sigma=\{ \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \cdots, \sigma_m \}$ algebra defined on it.

Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma$, let $S(\sigma) =\{A \in \sigma \mid A\cap B= \emptyset,  \forall B \in \sigma \setminus \{A, X \} \}$. And how can I prove that  $(\sigma)=(\sigma')$ implies $\sigma =\sigma′$ ?

Comment: What does "$\sigma_i==\sigma_j$" mean, and what does $S_i==S_j$ mean? And if you are trying to prove a "bijection" (for finite sets), then shouldn't you just be trying to show that $\sigma_0\subseteq S_0$? Is $\sigma_0$ a specific $\sigma$-algebra, or an arbitrary but fixed one?

Comment: $\sigma_o$ is an arbitrary but fixed one. $\sigma_i == \sigma_j$ was referring to two fixed arbitrary $\sigma_i$ and $sigma_j$ is the same. and my question is about given two fixed arbitrary $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$, obtain their subset $S_i$ and $S_j$, if $S_i$ is the same with $S_j$ then $\sigma_i$ is the same as $\sigma_j$

Comment: That does not seem to have anything to do with what you write in your second paragraph. It seems like, perhaps, you are doing the following? Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma$, let $S(\sigma)=\{A\in\sigma\mid A\cap B=\varnothing\text{ for all }B\in\sigma\setminus\{A,X\}\}$. And then you want to see whether $S(\sigma)=S(\sigma')$ implies $\sigma=\sigma'$?

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what i'm trying to do.

Comment: When you write "a bijection relationship $S_0$... with $\sigma_0$", it read to me like you are trying to establish a bijection between $S_0$ and $\sigma_0$, especially since your very next statement is that you already have $S_0\subseteq \sigma_0$. You should really rewrite this to make it clear.

Comment: "And also $\sigma=\sigma'$ implies $S(\sigma)=S(\sigma')$?" The second implication is trivial. The two sets in question are *identical* when $\sigma=\sigma'$.

Comment: right.. thanks for the comment, i'll update this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and define
$$
\sigma_1=\sigma(\{\{x_1\},\{x_2\}\})\quad\text{and}\quad\sigma_2=\sigma(\{\{x_3\},\{x_4\}\}).
$$
Then $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2$ but $S(\sigma_1)=S(\sigma_2)=\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: what is $\sigma_1 = \sigma(\{ \{x_1\}, \{x_2\}\})$ ?

Comment: It is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets $\{x_1\}$ and $\{x_2\}$, i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{x_1\}$ and $\{x_2\}$.

Comment: Right, but the requirement is all $\sigma$-algebra defined on $X$ or $\{ \emptyset, X \} \subset \sigma$

Comment: I can write out $\sigma_1$ explicitly for you if you like. $\sigma(\{\{x_1\},\{x_2\}\})=\{\{x_1\},\{x_2\},\{x_1,x_2\},\{x_3,x_4\},\{x_1,x_3,x_4\},\{x_2,x_3,x_4\},\{x_1,x_2,x_4,x_4\},\emptyset\}$.